# How do I rotate the symbols

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

As you can see I have rotated one of the symbols to face it upwards.
[image: Rotated symbol at the left]

I want to apply the same effect to each symbol individually

Unfortunately, if I rotate it as a group, the symbols will look like this
(It changed their position)

[image: Rotated symbols as a group]

So how do I rotate the symbols to face upwards without doing it individually and without changing their position? It's such a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an exact rotation you want to apply to each individual path...

Select all the paths to rotate.

**Right click > Transform each** and there you can select a rotation (among other transformations) for each individual path.

They will apply to every path individually.